# Delete part of row if checkbox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to make a tasklist in Google Sheets where I can check a checkbox (value true/untrue). At the end of the day I want to delete all the tasks in the tasklist that are checkt (marked as true). I know how to delete a whole row if a checkbox is checkt and my code works. But in this case I only need to delete the information from the checkbox from the column D till K. I don't want that any other information from any other column on the same row is beeing deleted.

Like I said, i have a working code. In the example sheet I have a example where I want to delete project Mario. The box is checked and now I want to delete the information from column D till column K.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EYxtzro_vk-gK1iReyjKQ-WwM5G9Jiu-h-55zuHMWXg/edit?usp=sharing

```
function deleteCells() { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');
var r = s.getRange('K:K');    
var v = r.getValues();  
for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
if(v[0,i]=='true')   
s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about what you want to do, if you want to delete the rows which have the checked checkboxes at the column "K" by running the function of `deleteCells()`, for example, how about modifying `if(v[0,i]=='true')` to `if(v[i][0] === true) {`? If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: I believe Tedinoz's answer below would work for you, although have you considered using the Google Tasks utility? it manages the information and you can work with it in Apps Script as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting the row, use `range.clear(options)` to delete the content and the formatting.
I created `var datasetrange = s.getRange(i+1,4,1,7);` to identify the range. Note that this is the range from Coluymn D to Column J

- `datasetrange.clear({contentsOnly: true});` - to delete the content
- `datasetrange.clear({formatOnly: true});` - to delete the formatting

Then as a separate exercise:

- `s.getRange(i+1,11).setValue(false);` - this is the range for cell "K6", and it changes the value of the checkbox from "true" to "false" (which assumes, BTW, that you used the default values for the checkbox).

---

```
 function so5763377101() { 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
      var s = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');
      var r = s.getRange('K:K');    
      var v = r.getValues();    
      var dataset = [];
      for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
      if(v[0,i]=='true') {  
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", checkbox = "+v[0,i]);
        var datasetrange = s.getRange(i+1,4,1,7);
        // Logger.log(datasetrange.getA1Notation());
        datasetrange.clear({contentsOnly: true});
        datasetrange.clear({formatOnly: true});
        s.getRange(i+1,11).setValue(false);    
      }
    }
```